# Checkboxes "on" by default when not checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form page with 39 check box fields. I am trying to use javascript to get the value of them. Each checkbox has a `name` attribute of `cb`.

I am running:

```
function getBoxes() {
    let boxes = $('input[name="cb"]');
    for(let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      console.log(boxes[i].value);
    }
  }
```

So I am getting an array of all of the checkbox inputs (they all have unique id's). If inside the loop I run `console.log(boxes[i].value)` it returns `on` for all 39 instances when NONE of them are in fact checked.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I am expecting it to return 0 or `off` or `NULL`

Also here is an example of one of the checkboxes:

`<input class="mx-2" type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb_c">`

All are the same they just have different id's

Comment: I would avoid using `.value` for checkbox state. Use `.checked` instead.

Comment: Overall we can say that altering the checked state of a checkbox doesn't modify its `value` property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch this line:

```js
console.log(boxes[i].value);
```

And give this a try instead:

```js
console.log(boxes[i].checked);
```

That will tell you if the checkbox is checked or not when the code is run. The value of a checkbox will be something like `on` as that's the value that will be used if the checkbox has indeed been checked.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I will accept the answer when it lets me